# How to highlight tree levels

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, highlighting, tikz-trees

How can i highlight tree levels to be some thing like that...[image]

I've drawn my tree with this code

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\large,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=60pt,
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    }}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\Tree [.Parent
        [.one 
            [.one1 
                   [.one11 
                        [.one111 ]
                        [.one112 ]
                        [.one113 ] ]
                   [.one12 ] 
                   [.one13 ] ] 
            [.one2 one21 ] ]
        [.two 
            [.two1 two11 ]
            [.two2 [.two21 two211 ]
                   [.two22 [.two221 two2211 ] 
                           [.two222 two321 ] ] ] ] 
        [.three
            [.three1 ] ] ]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility is to name some of the tree nodes, define some auxiliary nodes (for the text) and coordinates and then use the `fit` and `background` libraries to draw the background filling (the code can be simplified using `\foreach`, but this is left as an exercise):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,trees,backgrounds,fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\definecolor{myfilling}{RGB}{208,215,222}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\large,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=60pt,
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    },
filling/.style=
    {minimum height=12mm,
     draw=myfilling!75!black,
     very thick,
     drop shadow,
     rectangle,rounded corners,
     fill=myfilling,
    },
ntext/.style=
    {draw=none,
     text width=4cm,
     align=center
    },
}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
]
\Tree [.\node (p) {Parent};
        [.\node (o) {one}; 
            [.\node (1) {one1}; 
                   [.\node (11) {one11}; 
                        [.\node (111) {one111}; ]
                        [.one112 ]
                        [.one113 ] ]
                   [.one12 ] 
                   [.one13 ] ] 
            [.one2 one21 ] ]
        [.two 
            [.two1 two11 ]
            [.two2 [.two21 two211 ]
                   [.two22 [.two221 \node (2211) {two2211}; ] 
                           [.two222 two321 ] ] ] ] 
        [.three
            [.\node (31) {three1}; ] ] ]
\end{scope}
% auxuliary constructs for level 4
\node[left=of 111,ntext] 
  (text4) {Level 4 text};
\coordinate (aux2) at ([xshift=5pt]31.east|-text4);
% auxuliary constructs for level 3
\node[ntext] at (text4|-11) 
  (text3) {Level 3 text};
\coordinate (aux4) at ([xshift=5pt]31.east|-11);
% auxuliary constructs for level 2
\node[ntext] at (text4|-1) 
  (text2) {Level 2 text};
\coordinate (aux6) at ([xshift=5pt]31.east|-1);
% auxuliary constructs for level 1
\node[ntext] at (text4|-o) 
  (text1) {Level 1 text};
\coordinate (aux8) at ([xshift=5pt]31.east|-o);
% auxuliary constructs for level 0
\node[ntext] at (text4|-p) 
  (text0) {Level 0 text};
\coordinate (aux10) at ([xshift=5pt]31.east|-p);
% auxuliary constructs for level 5
\node[ntext] at (text4|-2211) 
  (text5) {Level 5 text};
\coordinate (aux12) at ([xshift=5pt]31.east|-2211);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[filling,fit=(text4) (aux2)] {};
\node[filling,fit=(text3) (aux4)] {};
\node[filling,fit=(text2) (aux6)] {};
\node[filling,fit=(text1) (aux8)] {};
\node[filling,fit=(text0) (aux10)] {};
\node[filling,fit=(text5) (aux12)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: who can i write text in the highlight?

Comment: @Misaki the background highlighting is a node, so you can use it to place text; in some minutes I'll update my answer with some text.

Comment: @Misaki please see my updated answer.

Comment: Too much typing ;).

Answer (score 5):

What I do here is inset the tree you created over a background that contains the yellow bars and text.  Care had to be taken to match up the right size of the yellow bars (with the `\rule` definition in `\crow` and the gap size (the `\vspace` in `\crow`).  I also set the width to 9".

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crow[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{9in}{%
  \rule[-5pt]{0pt}{25pt}\Huge\bfseries #1\hfill}}\par\vspace*{28pt}}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\large,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=60pt,
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    }}

\newsavebox{\myboxA}
\newsavebox{\myboxB}
\centering
\sbox{\myboxA}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.Parent
        [.one 
            [.one1 
                   [.one11 
                        [.one111 ]
                        [.one112 ]
                        [.one113 ] ]
                   [.one12 ] 
                   [.one13 ] ] 
            [.one2 one21 ] ]
        [.two 
            [.two1 two11 ]
            [.two2 [.two21 two211 ]
                   [.two22 [.two221 two2211 ] 
                           [.two222 two321 ] ] ] ] 
        [.three
            [.three1 ] ] ]

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\sbox{\myboxB}{\parbox{9in}{\crow{Parent}\crow{Level 1}\crow{Level 2}%
  \crow{Level 3}\crow{Level 4}\crow{Level 5}}}
\hsmash{\stackinset{r}{}{t}{3pt}{\usebox{\myboxA}}{\usebox{\myboxB}}}
\end{document}

{tikz-pgf}{graphics}{highlighting}{tikz-trees}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is just me practising by experimenting with a package I wrote to answer another question. That package is `justtrees` and it is a simplified version of `prooftrees` which I wrote out of frustration. Both packages provide a `forest` style and the new versions offer a corresponding environment which has various advantages.

This uses v0.03 of the package. Just ask if you feel brave enough to try it yourself!

The invocation of `right justifications` at the beginning ensures that `right just 1`, `right just 2` etc. are created even though no visible nodes are wanted there. It isn't necessary to add `left justifications` because `left just={<text>}` will ensure this happens anyway.

These nodes get automatically named and are then used to draw the background rectangles behind the tree. This has to be done using `forest`'s `end draw` because otherwise the rectangles are drawn on top of the tree, even if we try to place them on the `background` layer.

`just format` is used to specify the format of the level descriptors. Among other things, this ensures that their height matches that of the nodes in the main tree, which is needed to get appropriately sized background rectangles.

I'm quite surprised how well this worked, to be honest as I wouldn't trust my code for one minute.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{justtrees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  my node/.style={
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt,
  },
  level descriptors/.style={
    font=\sffamily,
    text=blue!75!black,
    minimum height=8mm,
    text depth = 0pt,
  },
  my edges/.style={
    draw=blue!50,
    ultra thick,
    rounded corners
  },
  my level fill/.style={
    draw=blue!75, fill=blue!20, drop shadow, rounded corners
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{justtree}
  {
    right justifications,
    just format/.append style={level descriptors},
    for tree={
      my node,
      edge={my edges},
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2mm-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      l sep+=2mm,
    },
    end draw/.code={
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
          \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
            \node [my level fill, fit=(left just \i.north west) (right just \i.south east)] {};}
        \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }
  [Parent, left just=level 1 descriptor
    [one, left just=level 2 descriptor
        [one1, left just=level 3 descriptor
             [one11, left just=level 4 descriptor
                    [one111, left just=level 5 descriptor]
                    [one112]
                    [one113]
              ]
              [one12]
              [one13]
        ]
        [one2
          [one21]
        ]
    ]
    [two
        [two1
          [two11]
        ]
      [two2
         [two21
            [two211]
         ]
         [two22
          [two221
            [two2211]
          ]
          [two222
            [two321, left just=level 6 descriptor]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [three
        [three1]
    ]
  ]
\end{justtree}

\end{document}
```

[image: justtrees level management]